# pyparsing, ignore can't ignore string inline

Tags: python, pyparsing

I want to use the pyparsing's commaSeparatedList to seperate a string and ignore the staff inside '{' '}'.

example:

```
a = 'xyz,abc{def,123,456}'
```

after parse, I want to got 
['xyz','abc{def,123,456}']

I wrote this:

```
 nested_expr = '{' + SkipTo('}') + '}'
 commaSeparatedList.ignore(nested_expr).parseString(a)
```

result: (['xyz', 'abc{def', '123', '456}'], {})

Actulally
It seems like when there is a separater before '{', this will work

```
a = 'xyz,abc,{def,123,456}'
commaSeparatedList.ignore(nested_expr).parseString(a)
```

result: (['xyz', 'abc', ''], {})

Could you take a look why this is happening?

Comment: Is it possible that the {}'s will nest? If not, try using `QuotedString('{',endQuoteChar='}')` to suppress comma detection inside the braces.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this QuotedString still not work,`a = 'xyz,abc{def,123,456}'; commaSeparatedList.ignore(QuotedString('{', endQuoteChar='}')).parseString(a)` still parse the common inside the '{','}'

Answer (score 0):

Open up the pyparsing.py source file and see how commaSeparatedList is implemented - it isn't that much, and easily adapted to your case:

```
# original
_commasepitem = Combine(OneOrMore(Word(printables, excludeChars=',') +
                                  Optional( Word(" \t") +
                                            ~Literal(",") + ~LineEnd() ) ) ).streamline().setName("commaItem")
commaSeparatedList = delimitedList( Optional( quotedString.copy() | _commasepitem, default="") ).setName("commaSeparatedList")


# modified
_commasepitem = Combine(OneOrMore(QuotedString('{',endQuoteChar='}',unquoteResults=False) | Word(printables, excludeChars=',{}') +
                                  Optional( Word(" \t") +
                                            ~Literal(",") + ~LineEnd() ) ) ).streamline().setName("commaItem")

commaSeparatedList = delimitedList( Optional(_commasepitem, default="") ).setName("commaSeparatedList")
```

It's important that the Word in _commasepitem *not* allow for inclusion of '{}' characters.